# Given an Int (IntValue) and a (bitPosition), how can I set the bit at bitPosition to either 1 or 0?

Tags: kotlin, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to understand bitwise operators in Kotlin. I have a 7 bit number and want to track the 7 days of a week and which days to water the grass, each day is represented by a specific bit.

var Sunday = 0b1000000
...
var Saturday = 0b0000001

Readying through the Kotlin documentation is appears this function would set a day (bitPosition) to 1:

```
fun setDayEnabled(day: Int) {
    scheduledWeek = scheduledWeek.or(day)
}
```

The Kotlin documentation says of OR: "If either of the bits is 1, it gives 1". But I have not found a way to specifically set a bit to zero. Is there a way to do this?

What I'd really prefer is just the ability to say "for the given Int, set the 4th bit position to 1 or 0". This seems like a very simple request, but none of the bitwise operators seem to be what I'm looking for.  I see this other class BitSet which has this functionality, but then I don't see a way to convert a BitSet to an Int, so that looks like the wrong choice. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var scheduledWeek = 0b0011000

fun setDayDisabled(dayMask: Int) {
    scheduledWeek = scheduledWeek and dayMask.inv()
}

fun main() {
    println(scheduledWeek)
    setDayDisabled(0b0010000)
    println(scheduledWeek)
}
```

This prints

```
24
8
```

If you want to do this by index, then first calculate the mask as:

```
dayMask = 1 shl dayIndex
```

The index should be 0-based.

Edit: I'm not too familiar with Kotlin, but I just realized it's probably more idiomatic to use the infix form (e. g. `a or b` instead of `a.or(b)`)